# Get Styles from LESS Javascript Implementation

Tags: css, less

I've been using the Javascript implementation of LESS for working on a project, and it works great, however I'm now finished the project and in an effort to improve site performance I'd like to get the processed version of the CSS to use directly, rather than running it through LESS every time.

Can someone tell me if/how it's possible to view the processed LESS styles on my website? Perhaps it's under the hood of developer tools or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a LESS compiler, here's the link from the LESS official site:

https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js

Answer (score 0):

[LESS](https://github.com/less/less.js) itself comes with a [command line compiler](https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/Command-Line-Usage).